# Subset a df using an if statement - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am hoping to create and return a subsetted `df` using an `if` statement. Specifically, for the code below, I have two different sets of values. The `df` I want to return will vary based on one of these values.

Using the code below, the specific value will be within `normal` and `different`. The value in `place` will dictate how the `df` will be subsetted.

Below is my attempt. The value in `place` will only ever be a single value, so it won't match the lists in full. Is it possible to return the `df` when the value in `place` is equal to a single value with these lists?

I'm hoping to return `df1` to be used for subsequent tasks.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'period' : [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0],                                
    })

place = 'a'

normal = ['a','b']
different = ['v','w','x','y','z']

different_subset_start = 2
normal_subset_start = 4
subset_end = 8

for val in df:
    if place in different:
        print('place is different')
        df1 = df[(df['period'] >= different_subset_start) & (df['period'] <= subset_end)].drop_duplicates(subset = 'period')
        return df1
    elif place in normal:
        print('place is normal')
        df1 = df[(df['period'] >= normal_subset_start) & (df['period'] <= subset_end)].drop_duplicates(subset = 'period')
        return df1
    else:
        print('Incorrect input for Day. Day Floater could not be scheduled. Please check input value')
    return
```

print(df1)

Intended output would be to return `df1` to be used later.

```
   period
2     2.0
4     3.0
5     4.0
6     5.0
7     7.0
9     8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if an object is *in* something rather than check if it *equal to* something, use `in`.

```
if place in different:
```

and similarly

```
elif place in normal:
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is how it should look if you make it a function. Basically, you just need to do a `def my_function_name(arguments):` sort of thing, then indent the rest of your code so it belongs to that function. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_subset(df, place):
    normal = ['a','b']
    different = ['v','w','x','y','z']

    different_subset_start = 2
    normal_subset_start = 4
    subset_end = 8

    if place in different:
        df1 = df[(df['period'] >= different_subset_start) & (df['period'] <= subset_end)].drop_duplicates(subset = 'period')
    elif place in normal:
        df1 = df[(df['period'] >= normal_subset_start) & (df['period'] <= subset_end)].drop_duplicates(subset = 'period')
    else:
        df1 = None
    return df1

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'period' : [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0],                             
    })

place = 'a'

print(get_subset(df, place))
```

Comment: Thanks @brentertainer. It it possible to return df1 outside of the `if` statement?

Comment: @jonboy When I read return, I think `return` -- like what you would write to return a value from from a function/method. Would you please clarify what you mean? There is no function/method in your example.

Comment: I'm learning as I go, I think I need a `function` where it returns the subsetted `df` based on the value in `place`

Comment: Sure, you can do that. You need to be careful to define `df1` in every case. If the `else` condition is reached in your code, `df1` will not be defined. So you might do `df1 = None` there or `df1 = pd.DataFrame()` to make it an empty DataFrame so at least it's the same type.

Comment: I've amended the question. It's still incorrect. But would something like this be amended

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. Just a quick one sorry. Where would I find some information regarding how this works. As in what each variable means and how it works togetehr.

Comment: @jonboy There is a [Beginners Guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers) on the official Python wiki. Start with any of the links there. Getting started can be difficult, but don't feel discouraged. As it's said, the best way to eat an elephant is one bite at a time. I regularly learn something new that makes me feel silly about the way I wrote a piece of code yesterday, a week ago, a year ago, etc. Best wishes to you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at `for val in df:` in your code.
Such a construction is strange, as you don't use `val` variable.

Change the last fragment of your code to something like this:

```
def fn():
    if place in different:
        print('place is different')
        return df[df.period.between(different_subset_start, subset_end)]\
            .drop_duplicates(subset='period')
    elif place in normal:
        print('place is normal')
        return df[df.period.between(normal_subset_start, subset_end)]\
            .drop_duplicates(subset = 'period')
    else:
        print('Incorrect input for place. Please check value')
```

In your case `subset = 'period'` is superfluous as *period* is the only
column in your DataFrame.

The last *return* is also not needed. If a function execution comes
to the end of code it returns without returning any value.

Yet another detail: If your *DataFrame* has a **single** column then
maybe a *Series* would be enough?